# Регулярное выражение для перевода координат в десятичные градусы

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Получаю данные Exif, в котором координаты предоставлены в формате:

```
55,46,27.3496 N
37,39,1.0767 E
```

Все найденные мной скрипты переводят в координаты используя исходные строки с градусами минутами и т.д.

```
36°57'9" N
```

Пример:

```
convertDMSToDD: function (dms) {
     let parts = dms.split(/[^\d+(\,\d+)\d+(\.\d+)?\w]+/);
     let degrees = parseFloat(parts[0]);
     let minutes = parseFloat(parts[1]);
     let seconds = parseFloat(parts[2].replace(',','.'));
     let direction = parts[3];

     console.log('degrees: '+degrees)
     console.log('minutes: '+minutes)
     console.log('seconds: '+seconds)
     console.log('direction: '+direction)

     let dd = degrees + minutes / 60 + seconds / (60 * 60);

     if (direction == 'S' || direction == 'W') {
       dd = dd * -1;
     } // Don't do anything for N or E
     return dd;
   }
```

и другие: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140189/converting-latitude-and-longitude-to-decimal-values

Но эти регулярки не разбирает мои значения в массив. Я не силен в регулярных выражениях, прошу помочь с составлением для моих значений. 
Можно в один массив используя строку  `55,46,27.3496 N 37,39,1.0767 E` или по отдельности для каждой из координат.

Comment: [`/(\d+),(\d+),(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s([NESW])/`](https://jsfiddle.net/4sef3t2n/)? [А ещё вот так можно, с этим же выражением](https://jsfiddle.net/4sef3t2n/1/).

Comment: В принципе `split(/[, ]/)` привел бы к тому же результату, если мы точно знаем что у нас координата и проверка формата не требуется

Comment: `s.split(/\W+/)` тоже бы сработала, если все строки соответствуют указанному формату. velocat, пожалуйста, уточните, как могут выглядеть строки (текст), которые содержат искомые совпадения.

Comment: Строка всегда принимает вид , где градусы минуты и секунды разделены запятой, но у секунд еще есть точка и далее через пробел одна из букв N E S W . 
т. е  всегда  формат такой как указан в начале `55,46,27.3496 N` или `37,39,1.0767 E`

Comment: Wiktor, cпасибо, Ваше регулярное выражение отлично мне подходит! 
https://jsfiddle.net/velo/7pd10z6n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать

```
const regex = /(\d+),(\d+),(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s([NESW])/;
```

[См. демо онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/Zz5ZBJ/1)

- `(\d+)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: одна и более цифр
- `,` - запятая
- `(\d+)` - Захватывающая подмаска №2: одна и более цифр
- `,` - запятая
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Захватывающая подмаска №3: одна и более цифр, потом необязательная последовательность точки + одной и более цифр
- `\s` - пробельный символ
- `([NESW])` - Захватывающая подмаска №4: `N`, `E`, `S` или `W`.

Пример кода на JavaScript:

```js
const regex = /(\d+),(\d+),(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s([NESW])/;
const string = "55,46,27.3496 N";

get_decimaldegree(string);

function get_decimaldegree(str) {
  let [_, degrees, minutes, seconds, direction] = regex.exec(str);
  let dd = parseFloat(degrees) + (parseFloat(minutes) / 60) + (parseFloat(seconds) / (60 * 60));
  document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>\n" + dd + "\n\n\n" + degrees + "\n" + minutes + "\n" + seconds + "\n" + direction + "\n\n\n" + degrees + "\n" + (minutes / 60) + "\n" + (seconds / (60 * 60)) + "</pre>";
}
```